# Are pages moved to the disk when the process is scheduled?

Tags: operating-systems, memory-management, virtual-memory, paging

When process A has run long enough and the scheduler decides to run process B, will all the pages of process A be moved to the disk or they remain in the main memory?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A page is a part of RAM memory. It will never move to the disk, unless one of two happen:

1. The program specifically asked to store the memory in the disk (obviously, the memory will move to the disk)
2. There isn't enough RAM to store all of the memory of all processes combined. In this case, some processes' memory will be transferred to a designated area. When that process will need to run, it will be transferred back and once again memory of some other program will be placed there, if needed.

Comment: Ohh okay that cleared it out!